# Issue calling a JavaScript function in google appengine web app

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-app-engine, web-applications, web.xml

I'm trying to call a JavaScript function located in a separate .js file, but for some strange reason, it doesn't work. I literally tried all the possible relative paths and locations of .js file but nothing helped.

This works fine:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red; background-color: burlywood">
    <p id="debug"></p>
</div>
<script>
    function hello() {
        document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = "hello";
    }
</script>
```

Then I create "hello.js" in my webapp folder, paste function ... {} into it, and change  to:

```
<script src="hello.js"></script>
```

And it doesn't work! I tried /hello.js, /webapp/hello.js and numerous other combinations. 
I think it has something to do with the fact that it's a web app for appengine, not a website, but I can't figure out how do I need to specify the path to my .js file correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: I think my issue is exactly the same as here: https://coderanch.com/t/523941/java/JSP-Identify-JS-CSS-file but I can't reproduce the solution

Comment: What does your `app.yaml` look like?

Comment: Hey Brett, I've actually fixed it yesterday by properly accounting for *.js files in my appengine-web.xml (same as app.yaml but for java runtime). Will post it as an answer should anyone else face the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by modifying my appengine-web.xml file. Apparently all the *.js files must be included in < static-files> section. I've added the following to the file:

```
  <static-files>
    <include path="/js/**.js" />
  </static-files>
```

Placed all the *.js files to webapp/js/, and used the following src attribute:

```
<script src="js/file_name.js"></script>
```

Everything works fine now. The only thing to be cognizant of is that static files are being cached, so it's better to develop and debug js code within jsp files first and then move the final version to a .js file.